# Hard logic - Reversing a format

Tags: java, io, logic

I have this code which reads from a file:

```
dummy = fd.readLong();
for(i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
    dummy2=fd.readLong();
    chunksizes[i] = dummy2- dummy;
    dummy = dummy2;
}
```

I now have a list of chunk sizes and I want to write them in the format above. I have an array called actualSizes which is the sizes I want to write, I have the amount of chunks. Any psuedocode that could do this? My head is going crazy yet it looks so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the file has a list of *offsets* and that you load them into an array as deltas (chunk sizes):

```java
0    100   250   420   580    Offsets from file
└──┬──┴──┬──┴──┬──┴──┬──┘
  100   150   170   160       Deltas, aka chunk sizes
```

You then say:

> I now have a list of chunk sizes and I want to write them in the format above.

The only "format above" would be the list of *offsets*, so you create a list of offsets from a list of delta (chunk/actual) sizes, by starting with `0` and writing a running sum:

```java
long offset = 0;
fd.writeLong(offset);
for (long size : actualSizes) {
    offset += size;
    fd.writeLong(offset);
}
```

```java
  120   140   130   150       actual sizes
┌──┴──┬──┴──┬──┴──┬──┴──┐
0    120   260   390   540    offsets in file (running total)
```

Comment: I just managed to figure it out https://pastebin.com/PCtuJHq7. The first number was the size of the file header and then the size was added on too. But I understand now so thank you!